# Can Sybase ASE 12.5.4 32 bit drivers be installed alongside their 64 bit counterparts?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, sybase, sap-ase

I'm migrating users from x86 Windows XP machines to x64 Windows 7 machines and some applications require Sybase drivers to be 32 bit, while others require it to be 64 bit.

Is it possible to install drivers for both architectures alongside one another?

I've had a good Google but there doesn't seem to be much information on this.

Many thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you would probably need batch wrappers around them to change the environment.

You'd have to install sybase 32 bit and 64 bit seperately (say C:\SYB32 and C:\SYB64)

You'd then need to switch the SYBASE variable between the two directories, as well as changing the PATH variable to have the correct sybase lib directory in it. (when you install sybase it adds to your path - best idea would be to remove it from the system config under properties of my computer and only add on the one you need)

The PATH is what determines what sybase libraries are loaded, and the SYBASE variable then determines where those libraries load their resources from.

you may or may not have to change the SYBASE_JRE6 to the value in SYBASE_JRE6_32 or SYBASE_JRE6_64

eg:

```
:CheckOS
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (GOTO 64BIT) ELSE (GOTO 32BIT)
:64BIT
SET SYBASE=C:\Syb64
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\syb64\ASE-15_0\jobscheduler\bin;C:\syb64\ASE-15_0\dll;C:\syb64\ASE-15_0\bin;C:\syb64\DBISQL\bin;C:\syb64\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\syb64\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\syb64\UAF-2_5\bin;C:\syb64\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\syb64\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\syb64\OCS-15_0\bin;
GOTO END
:32BIT
SET SYBASE=C:\Syb32
SET PATH=%PATH$;C:\syb32\ASE-15_0\jobscheduler\bin;C:\syb32\ASE-15_0\dll;C:\syb32\ASE-15_0\bin;C:\syb32\DBISQL\bin;C:\syb32\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\syb32\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\syb32\UAF-2_5\bin;C:\syb32\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\syb32\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\syb32\OCS-15_0\bin;
GOTO END
:END
```

Note: I haven't tested any of this, but it should be enough to get you started.